Error with sqlite3 in docker container. Exec format error
I'm working on a small hobby project where i have a backend that uses sqlite3 for the database. Then i want to dockerize it and eventually host it somewhere.
My problem is showcased below, i have googled high and low for a fix for this problem. But to no avail.
Things i have already tried that did not work

add node_modules to .dockerignore
remove sqlite3, clean yarn cache, reinstall sqlite3
remove node_modules and running yarn install
I read somewhere that the binaries for some npm packages could be bundled for windows (which i work on) and then, somehow, get used in the container which is linux based. But since yarn install is being run in the dockerfile, i cant see how that would be the problem.

My dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000

When running my docker container i do:
docker build -t my-app .

And then
docker run -dp 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 my-app

The problem
But in my docker container logs i get the following error:
2024-06-10 20:43:52 yarn run v1.22.19
2024-06-10 20:43:52 $ nodemon app.ts
2024-06-10 20:43:52 [nodemon] 3.1.0
2024-06-10 20:43:52 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2024-06-10 20:43:52 [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
2024-06-10 20:43:52 [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
2024-06-10 20:43:52 [nodemon] starting `ts-node app.ts`
2024-06-10 20:43:53 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2024-06-10 20:43:53 Error: Error loading shared library /app/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node: Exec format error
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1460:18)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:1:37)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
2024-06-10 20:43:53     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43) {
2024-06-10 20:43:53   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
2024-06-10 20:43:53 }


just create
.dockerignore

then add
.dockerignore
node_modules

then rebuild docker
